# Парсинг динамических данных на C#

Tags: c#, html, парсер

Здравствуйте! У меня появилась задача : парсить данные с [этого](https://csgo500.com/) сайта (Мне нужны количество поставленной валюты на каждую из команд и победитель прокрутки). Сначала это показалось мне простой затеей - просто скачиваем HTML сайта и выбираем нужные данные. Но этот сайт оказался динамическим, и я не знаю, как из него достать данные (они всегда равны 0). Как можно их запарсить?

Так, я разобрался с тем, что данные можно получить и понял их структуру. Теперь возникает новый вопрос : как эти данные "взять"? Я слышал, что это можно сделать с помощью веб-сокетов, в .Net даже класс есть - System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket. Но документанции по этому классу я не нашел, по этому и прошу привести пример использования данного класса.

Comment: что значит `оказался динамическим`?

Comment: это значит, что данные в нем загружаются не один раз при загрузке страницы из html файла, а в реальном времени откуда-то еще

Comment: ну так и вы грузите оттуда же их, откуда сайт грузит. Или в чем проблема?

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но как узнать место, откуда сайт загружает??

Comment: открываете сайт, нажимаете F12 - открываются инструменты разработчика. Ищете там вкладку Network - вкладку со всеми http запросами с сайта, и там ищете нужные вам запросы.

Comment: Нашел вкладку "WebSocket", в ней много информации (в том числе и нужной). Как эту информацию можно извлечь?

Comment: Веб сокеты немного другая тема, я тут не помощник, но добавье эту инфу в ворос

Comment: selenium посмотрите, можете воспользоваться плагином для firefox называется selenium IDE, там есть конвертер кода в c#

Comment: К сожалению, селениум не подойдет, на сколько я понял. Нужно именно вебсокетом подключиться к сайту и выкачивать все приходящие данные